# Mantener vista al recargar página

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Tengo un **select (HTML)** y cuando se elige una opción, se carga un formulario vía **JS** abajo del select.

Luego, envío el formulario para guardar los datos que necesito, se recarga la página y el formulario desaparece.

Lo que necesito es mantener la opción elegida en el select y que el  formulario se vea.

Estoy trabajando en **laravel** por las dudas y también **angular**.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no usas AJAX para enviar el formulario? Así mantienes el formulario visible.

Answer (score 1):

En un lenguaje de servidor como Laravel (framework de PHP) puedes guardar variables en la sesión por ejemplo y a la hora de cargar la página decidir en función de la variable de la sesión si quieres mostrar algo, cargar... [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417796/set-session-variable-in-laravel) una referencia a StackOverflow en inglés.

También (si usas HTML5) puedes utilizar web storage. [Aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) la referencia de la W3C.

Por último mediante una variable en la URL puedes hacerlo. Ejemplo:

```
http://miweb.com/mipagina.php?opcionSelect=1
```

Así podrás al momento de cargar tu página establecer en el  el valor que trae la variable.

Comment: Esta bien, eso lo entiendo, pero yo tengo un div oculto, y cuando elijo algo del select (envio un post via ajax) , ahí se muestra ese div (formulario). De la forma que vos decís, no se como tomar el evento del select y mostrar el formulario al recargar la página

Comment: Podrías añadir código a la consulta y poder ayudarte mejor? @JuanPabloB

Answer (score 1):

> Envío el formulario para guardar los datos que necesito, se recarga la página y el formulario desaparece. Lo que necesito es **mantener la opción elegida** en el select y **que el formulario se vea**.

Hacerlo de esa manera no le brinda una buena UX al usuario. Si usas angular debes aprovechar lo que te brinda para hacer una aplicación rica en UX y funcionalidad. Lo que deseas hacer se puede lograr simplemente usando AJAX. Angular provee el módulo [`http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) para ésto.

```
$scope.crearAlgo = function () {
  $http.post('//localhost/app/controlador/crear', $scope.nuevoAlgo)
    .then(function (response) => {
      alert('Algo creado satisfactoriamente');
      // asignar un objeto vacío a 'nuevoAlgo' para resetear sus valores
      $scope.nuevoAlgo = {};
    });
}
```

En el formulario HTML ligas cada control con una propiedad de `nuevoAlgo`.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlgo.nombre"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlgo.apellidos"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="nuevoAlgo.email"/>
```

Lo que pasará es lo siguiente:

1. Conforme escribas en los inputs, el valor será asignado a la propiedad ligada mediante `ng-model`.
2. Se envía el formulario mediante AJAX.
3. Cuando el servidor haya respondido, restablecemos el objeto y por ende, los inputs.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = { };
  $scope.option = ''; /* para mostrar/ocultar el formulario */
  $scope.create = function () {
    // lo comento porque no es posible hacer peticiones AJAX en el sitio
    /*$http.post('//localhost/ejemplo/usuarios/crear', $scope.user
    )
    .then(function (response) {
       $scope.user = {};
    });*/
    $scope.user = { };
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <select ng-model="option">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="show">Mostrar</option>
  </select>
  
  <form ng-show="option == 'show'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastname" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="create()" value="Registrar"/>
  </form>
</div>
```